# Express route path not working in production

Tags: http, docker, express, routes

I am new to Express.

I am using Docker.

I am using Caddy to proxy /api/vision to my Express instance listening at :3000.

I am trying to access my route in production but I get the classic 'Cannot GET ... ' error. I don't have this error with the same environment set up in development.

**Caddyfile:**

```
localhost:80 {  ## change to mydomain.app in production
  root frontend/ ## front end static files
  proxy /api/vision vision:3000 ## proxy to docker container
}
```

**app.js:**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/vision', (req, res) => {
  res.send({message: 'Hello World!'});
});

app.listen(port);
```

This all works fine when I run Docker at localhost on my development machine.

It gives me the front end, and /api/vision correctly redirects to :3000.

Once I deploy to my production machine, and send a request to mydomain.app/api/vision, Express gives me:

```
Cannot GET /api/vision
```

Is there some secret black magic going on in Express? I am at a loss here. I must have missed something, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I made a terrible mistake when syncing files and the problem is now solved. Thank you